# Conflict between scale_fill_manual and scale_x_discrete in a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to control the order in which factors are plotted, and assign them specific colors.  I'm fairly new to `ggplot2`, being a recent and reluctant convert from base graphics.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(fac = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"),
                 val = c(10, 4, 7))  
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = fac, y = val, fill = fac)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red", "orange")) +
       scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))
```

[image]

I want "Obey the Cowgod" to be blue, "Three little pigs" to be red, and "Cereal Killer" to be orange.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the order of the levels of your column as a factor.

```
df$fac <- factor(df$fac, levels = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))
```

Now the colors will be assigned to the correct names.

(Edit note: As Gregor pointed out in comments, scale_x_discrete is not needed anymore)

Full code:

```
df <- data.frame(fac = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"),
                 val = c(10, 4, 7))

df$fac <- factor(df$fac, levels = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = fac, y = val, fill = fac)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red", "orange"))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

One - leave your data as-is and use a named vector for the fill `values`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = fac, y = val, fill = fac)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("Obey the Cowgod" = "blue", "Three Little Pigs" = "red", "Cereal Killer" = "orange")) +
       scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))
```

Two - edit your data by making the order of the factor levels in the order you want to plot, as in Cihan's answer. I like this one better, it got posted as I was writing it up :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not rely on the automatic conversion of strings to factors.  In the code provided the levels are given in alpha order.

```
df <- data.frame(fac = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"),
                 val = c(10, 4, 7))

levels(df$fac)
# [1] "Cereal Killer"     "Obey the Cowgod"   "Three Little Pigs"
```

By  explicityly setting `df$fac` as a factor with the levels in the order you want your ggplot code will not need to change.

```
df <- data.frame(fac = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"),
                 val = c(10, 4, 7),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$fac <- factor(df$fac, levels = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))

levels(df$fac)
# [1] "Obey the Cowgod"   "Three Little Pigs" "Cereal Killer"
```

no need to change the ggplot code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = fac, y = val, fill = fac)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red", "orange")) +
       scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Obey the Cowgod", "Three Little Pigs", "Cereal Killer"))
```

[image]